# Coffee ratings: How to do causal inference with high kurtosis/outliers?

Tags: regression, python, least-squares, outliers, statsmodels

I have data (n>1000) on ratings of various coffee features, and then a final overall score. I am interested in inference: What is the effect of a feature on overall score.

However, my data has skewness of 0.255 (not bad) and kurtosis of 16 (bad).

Looking at the residual histogram and qqplot, the fat tails are very evident. I.e: I have some (about 7) strong outliers.

What can I do to be able to draw statistical inferences (CIs, significance) from the data? There is nothing really unique about the 7 that warrant removing them.

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import seaborn as sns

# Read in data 
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jldbc/coffee-quality-database/master/data/arabica_data_cleaned.csv"
s=requests.get(url).content
df=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))

# Drop row of zeros 
df.drop(1310, inplace=True)

# Select IV columns
IVs = ["Aftertaste", "Balance", "Flavor"]
DV = ["Cupper.Points"]

# Get data
X = df[IVs]
y = np.log(df[DV])

# make model
mod = sm.OLS(y, X).fit(cov_type = "HC2")

# Print results 
results = mod.summary()
print(results)

# Plot residuals 
print("\nRESIDUALS\n")
r = pd.DataFrame(mod.resid)
sns.distplot(r)
plt.show()

# QQ plot 
fig = sm.qqplot(r)
```

```
                                 OLS Regression Results                                
=======================================================================================
Dep. Variable:          Cupper.Points   R-squared (uncentered):                   0.999
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared (uncentered):              0.999
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                          6.149e+05
Date:                Sun, 07 Jul 2019   Prob (F-statistic):                        0.00
Time:                        16:06:07   Log-Likelihood:                          1942.4
No. Observations:                1310   AIC:                                     -3879.
Df Residuals:                    1307   BIC:                                     -3863.
Df Model:                           3                                                  
Covariance Type:                  HC2                                                  
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aftertaste     0.0586      0.009      6.204      0.000       0.040       0.077
Flavor         0.1208      0.011     11.460      0.000       0.100       0.141
Balance        0.0890      0.009      9.683      0.000       0.071       0.107
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                      295.707   Durbin-Watson:                   1.174
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):            10031.357
Skew:                           0.255   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Kurtosis:                      16.547   Cond. No.                         99.8
==============================================================================
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I understand you are interested in inference, but your use of "causal" inference raises a red flag. Causality (*causation $\ne$ correlation*!) describes a subset of inferential problems that have specific extra requirements. Causal inference is 1) described temporally or at least sequentially, 2) involves an asymmetry $"A \implies B" \implies P(B|A,X) \sim 1, P(\bar{A}|\bar{B},X) \sim 1,  P(B|A,X) \sim P(B|X)$ 3) involves a plausible phenomenological argument that shows on a microscopic level just how $A$ starts a chain of interactions that result in $B$. Perhaps you mean plain old prediction?

Comment: Sure, perhaps I mispoke. I want to be able to say something about CIs and significance, even if there is no causal relationship.

Comment: Some comments: i) You omit the intercept in your model which alters the residuals (i.e. they don't have mean 0 anymore), ii) you should probably mention that you take the logarithm of the total score for your models.

Comment: [Correction above (too late to edit)  the last conditional should be $P(A|B,X)∼P(A|X)$ rather than $P(B|A,X) \sim P(B|X)$.]

Comment: OK, great. Whew! "Causal inference" is either very hard or very easy. Regarding your effort to model cupper.points with predictor variables, you are free to exclude outliers if you simply report that you do. Run the model with and without outliers. Do the standard errors improve? If your conclusions don't change, don't worry about outliers. If they do, you make a condition that your model is valid and accurate if your outlier condition is satisfied. Much more important is multi collinearity, nonlinear transformations of variables & other conditionals that could help/hurt your model.

Comment: If there is nothing unique about the 7 outliers that warrant removing them, then don't. Your mean square errors will be higher, but so will your generalizability. That is, your predictions on training and testing data will be similar, albeit with a higher MSE than if you removed the outliers. That's good. But perhaps it could be better, which is where the real work begins.

Comment: I'd consider a *robust* linear model: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/rlm.html

Answer (score 1):

If you examine this 3D scatter plot and 3D surface plot, you can see that the data is concentrated in one 3-space region on the left side of the images. From the "Y = a  + (b * X1) + (c * X2)" linear regression surface plot, it appears that the region with a high data density is much more vertical than the fitted surface. In my personal opinion, the "body" and "clean cup" data alone is insufficient to characterize "cupper.points" and additional data is needed.

[image: scatterplot]

[image: surfaceplot]